# Comparing ranges and copy entire row, when some cells match?

Tags: excel, compare, rows, vba

I'd like to compare 2 ranges in 2 different sheets.

`Sheet1("Raport")` contains undetailed customer information and types of product they should get.
`Sheet2("Dane")` contains detailed information about customers, which should (as 1 customer = entire row) be copied into specific sheets (e.g. `Sheet3("Produkt1")`, `Sheet4("Produkt2")` etc, based on customers and products list (`Sheet1("Raport")`).

Deleting the empty rows (works)

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows1()
    Dim i As Long

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Range of Produkt1 (works)

```
Sub SelectBetween()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long

    findrow = Range("B:B").Find("Produkt1", Range("B1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("B:B").Find("Laczna ilosc Produkt1", Range("B" & findrow)).Row
    Range("B" & findrow + 1 & ":M" & findrow2 - 1).Select
End Sub
```

Range of Produkt2 (works)

```
Sub SelectBetween2()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long

    findrow = Range("B:B").Find("Produkt2", Range("B1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("B:B").Find("Laczna ilosc Produkt2", Range("B" & findrow)).Row
    Range("B" & findrow + 1 & ":M" & findrow2 - 1).Select
End Sub
```

What should I write at "If" to compare sheets and copy detailed customer info to another sheet?

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, w3 As Worksheet
    Dim findrow1 As Long, findrow2 As Long
    Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, c As Range

    Set w1 = Worksheets("Raport")
    Set w2 = Worksheets("Dane")
    Set w3 = Worksheets("Produkt1")

    findrow1 = w1.Range("B:B").Find("Produkt2", w1.Range("B1")).Row
    findrow2 = w1.Range("B:B").Find("Laczna ilosc Produkt2", w1.Range("B" & findrow1)).Row
    Set range1 = w1.Range("B" & findrow1 + 1 & ":M" & findrow2 - 1)
    Set range2 = w2.Range("2:137")

    If range1 = w2.range2 Then
        range2.EntireRow.Copy w3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
    End If
End Sub
```

In attachment there's a file with final results (detailed customer info is simply copied in Produkt1 and Produkt2 Sheets without using macros). -> https://uploadfiles.io/ttmck

Answer (score 0):

After you copied desired range with

```
range2.EntireRow.Copy
```

next line should be pasting:

```
Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
```

replace `Worksheets(1)` with your destination. This will place all copied rows to consecutive rows on destination sheet, you will probably need to aply `RemoveDuplicates` to that range finally.